# Misner, Thorne & Wheeler's book "Gravitation" page 472-473 section 20.6, why $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B}$ is NOT ALWAYS zero in (20.40)?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

(The context of this topic is that, section 20.6 of this book derives Maxwell equations from Einstein field equation.)

On page 472~473 (section 20.6) of Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler's book *Gravitation*, it reads:

> Step five: The determinant of the coefficients in the four equations (20.38) for the four unknowns (20.39) has the value
> $| F^\mu_\beta | = - (\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B}) ^2   \space \space \space \space (20.40) $

> (see exercise 20.6, part i). In the generic case, this one function of the four variables (t, x, y, z) vanishes on one or more hypersurfaces; but off any such hypersurface (i.e., at "normal points" in spacetime) it differs from zero. At all normal points, the solution of the four linear equations (20.38) with their **nonvanishing determinant** gives identically zero for the four unknowns (20.39); that is to say, Maxwell's "equations of motion"
> $ F^\beta _v = 0 $
> are fulfilled and must be fulfilled as a straight consequence of Einstein's field equation (20.31)-plus expression 20.32 for the stress-energy tensor. Special cases admit counterexamples (see exercise 20.8); but in the generic case one need not invoke Maxwell's equations of motion; one can deduce them from the Einstein field equation.

Here is the screenshot of these pages:

[image: page 471]

...

[image: page 472]

...

[image: page 473]

The words "nonvanishing determinant" means that the value of expression (20.40) is not zero, which means $(\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B})$ is not zero.

My question:
I remember that $\vec{E}$ is always perpendicular to $\vec{B}$ in Maxwell Equation. So, why is $(\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B})$ not always zero in (20.40)?

B.T.W, it reads, about the term "generic case", on page 481: (f) In the "generic case" where the field (E, B) at the point of interest is not null, ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get a bar magnet. Its field points in all directions.  Move it next to a sheet of charge with its nearly uniform ${\bf E}$ field. The resulting ${\bf E}$ and ${\bf B}$ fields cannot  not be everywhere perpendicular.

Only in plane waves  will you find  ${\bf E}\cdot {\bf B}=0$ everywhere.

Comment: Yes! Physics is *physical*. It is not mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is that true for $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ in Maxwell equation? Because the context of my question deals with Maxwell equation. Sorry for this ambiguity in my original post.

Comment: Of course this is compatible with solutionsof  Maxwell's equation. Maxwell applies to *all* E&M phenomena, not just EM waves.

Comment: What's more, while $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ for a single plane wave, a superposition of two or more plane-wave solutions will generally have $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B} \neq 0$.